# How to find/replace python statement with multiple lines and keep the correct indentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, ide, editor

I'd like to find one statement in multiple python source files and replace all of those with multiple statements, but I don't know how to retain the correct indentations. Here is a simple example:

```
print("Hello World!")
if i == 0:
  print("Hello World!")
    if j == 0:
      print("Hello World!")
```

I want to replace all the `print("Hello World!");` with multiple lines:

```
print("Hello")
print("World")
print("!")
```

AND keep the correct indentation, so here is the expected result:

```
print("Hello")
print("World")
print("!")
if i == 0:
  print("Hello")
  print("World")
  print("!")
    if j == 0:
      print("Hello")
      print("World")
      print("!")
```

This is just a simple example, not the exact same find/replace problem I'm having. I just want to know how to do this kind of replacement generally. Is there any method to achieve this easily? Any editor/IDE can help? Thank you.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: your indentation is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Code or any other editor with Regular Expression Find-Replace

Find `([ \t]*)print\("Hello World!"\)`

Replace `$1print("Hello")\n$1print(" World")\n$1print("!")`

Some editors (Notepad++, ...) use `\1` to reference a capture group

Replace `\1print("Hello")\n\1print(" World")\n\1print("!")`